# Android Studio dando erro

Tags: android-studio, gradle

O meu Android studio ta dando esse erro e já tentei de tudo mas nada deu certo[[image: ]A imagem mostra o erro da api[1]]

Comment: Tente ver se você acha uma pasta (possivelmente oculta) chamada "`.gradle`" na raiz do seu projeto (observe o ponto no começo do nome). Se encontrar, tente deletar ela e recompilar tudo.

Comment: Outra coisa a tentar é deletar a pasta "`C:\Users\User\.gradle`". Novamente, veja que o nome começa com um ponto.

Comment: Eu apago a pasta e o dawload inicia mas depois de um tempo ele para e da o erro novamente

Answer (score 0):

Feche o Android Studio e apague a pasta a seguir. Ela será automaticamente baixada pela IDE na próxima vez em que você abri-la:

macOS: `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

Windows: `C:\Users\seu-usuario\\.gradle\wrapper\dists`

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801113/4319922)

Comment: Eu apago a pasta e o dawload inicia mas depois de um tempo ele para e da o erro novamente

Comment: Desinstalar e reinstalar o Android Studio é uma opção?

Comment: ja tentei e não foi tbm

Comment: Seu Android Studio funcionava normalmente e parou de funcionar? Se sim, lembra-se do que fez? Ou sempre deu esse problema?

Comment: sempre deu esse problema, nunca consegui fazer nada nele por conta dese erro

Comment: Você consegue ler em inglês? Tente seguir o que o usuário ensina nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43203001/4319922), para instalar e configurar externamente o Gradle para trabalhar no Android Studio.